# rmarkdown::render() does not pass -shell-escape options from pandoc to pdflatex

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I want to render an Rmarkdown file that requires the `-shell-escape` option in pdflatex or `--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape` option in pandoc. I specified `pandoc_args: "--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape"` in my YAML header, but rmarkdown::render() seems to call programs in this order:

1. knitr::knit() to *.md
2. encoding conversion to *.utf8.md
3. pandoc to *.tex (`pandoc mwe.utf8.md --to latex --output mwe.tex ...`)
4. pdflatex to *.pdf (`pdflatex mwe.tex`)

render() loses my `-shell-escape` option between steps 3 and 4, and I get an error since pdflatex cannot pass a command to the shell. Is there a way to either: 1) have pandoc output a *.pdf file instead of *.tex, or 2) pass `-shell-escape` onto pdflatex?

#### MWE: mwe.Rmd

```
---
title: "mwe"
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{sips -s format png #1 --out \OutputFile}
  \PrependGraphicsExtensions{.tif, .tiff}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: "--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape"
---

![](image.tif)
```

Running `$ rmarkdown::render("mwe.Rmd", output_file="mwe.pdf")` in R console gives the error since pdflatex was not called with `-shell-escape`:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `image-tif-converted-to.png' not found.

Error: Failed to compile mwe.tex. See mwe.log for more info.
```

Running `$ knitr::knit("mwe.Rmd")` in R console followed by `$ pandoc mwe.md -o mwe.pdf` in the terminal returns the correct PDF. Alternatively, running `$ pandoc mwe.md -s -o mwe.tex; pdflatex -shell-escape mwe.tex` on the intermediate tex file in the terminal also returns the correct PDF.

TIF image obtained from: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Chi_Recombination_Model_for_Wikipedia.tif

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue when trying to import the latex package minted - this R code near the beginning of my `.rmd` file fixed it for me:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    options(tinytex.engine_args = '-shell-escape')
```
````

I'm compiling the document with RStudio and sweave, on MacOS 10.14.6 if that's relevant. Hope this helps!